# Expression with multiple { } blocks

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression (in PHP) that matches any of these texts:

```
#{text}
#{text1}{text2}
#{text1}{numbers}{text2}
#{text1}{text with spaces}{numbers}{text2}
```

And so. Basically the first block could only hold text without spaces, yet the rest could hold anything. And after that, getting as matches those text1...numbers, etc. I've been trying with some regexp, yet it didn't make it. Here's the last one:

```
/#{(\w+)}({([\ a-zA-Z0-9*])})*/U
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Just like @stema suggested, I changed my regexp to this one:

```
/#\{(\w+)\}(\{([^}]*)\})*/
```

I avoided the Ungreedy flag because it was not helping the expression at all :). However, the results are not as many as I needed:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(42) "#{text1}{text with spaces}{numbers}{text2}"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "text1"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "{text2}"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "text2"
}
```

It seems that the inbetween parameters are not parsed (which looks weird to me).

Comment: It fails: When trying to parse the last example (with 4 blocks), I get these matches: #{text1} and text1

Comment: it seems you are only mathing one character inside the 2nd brace `{([\ a-zA-Z0-9*])}` should be something like `{([\ a-zA-Z0-9*]+)}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue I see is that the quantifier is misplaced

```
/#{(\w+)}({([\ a-zA-Z0-9*])})*/U
                        ^
```

should be outside the character class

```
/#{(\w+)}({([\ a-zA-Z0-9]*)})*/U
```

If the content in the following braces could be anything than you could do this

```
/#\{(\w+)\}(\{([^}]*)\})*/U
```

`[^}]` is a negated character class that matches anything but the closing curly bracket.

I also escaped the curly braces, since they have a special meaning as part of a quantifier. Some languages will match them literally when they do not form such a quantifier, but for clarity its better to always escape them, when they should be matched.

**Update:**

You can make one of your groups an non-capturing group, since you don't seem to need it

```
/#\{(\w+)\}(?:\{([^}]*)\})*/
```

this should give you this result

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(42) "#{text1}{text with spaces}{numbers}{text2}"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "text1"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "text2"
}
```

but you will always get only the last match of the repeated group in your resulting array, because each match is stored at `array[2]`. The second match will overwrite the first, the third the second ...

What you could do is to use the regex for format validation and then do a split e.g. something like this

```
$in = "#{text1}{text with spaces}{numbers}{text2}";
$result = preg_split('/}{|#{|}/', $in, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: +1. I would also escape the braces. Not all regular expression engines are smart enough to deduce from context that they are not meant as a quantifier here and will throw an error on compilation.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I added it to my answer.

Comment: You can avoid the first block using `+` instead of `*`

Comment: @dresende No, because the first block could hold different characters than the following.

Comment: that @stema said was correct. By the way, I edited my question a little bit

Comment: Oh, is your last update true? Damn, then. Isn't there any way to capture each repetition for the last group? Thanks in advance

Comment: well, you truly solved my problem, mate. Thanks! Here comes an ok and a +1 for all your help

Comment: @stema you're right, I read the question but when I read your answer completely forgot about that :P +1

Answer (score 2):

Following stema's answer I would suggest

1. validating the string with your regex
2. as you can't use capturing groups for this purpose I would strip out the leading `#{` and the trailing `}` and then `split` the string on this regex `}{`

This should give you an array of all the matches.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Joanna! I'm giving you a +1 because of this good idea, too. However, @stema's was more complete so, I have to accept his.